# Matrix exponential using Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, matrix-exponential

I'm trying to calculate the matrix exponential $e^{At}$ for $$A=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&-1\\2&-2&0\\1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

I found the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=-1, \lambda_3=0$ which give the eigenvectors $$v_{\lambda_{1,2}}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},v_{\lambda_3}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
I now would like to find the matrices $S$ and $J$ so that $$A=SJS^{-1}$$
Constructing these matrices requires another column vector. I now try to find the generalized eigenvector for eigenvalue $-1$ as follows. $$(A-(-1)I)\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2&-1/2\\1&0&0\\1/2&-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
But this has no solution, so I am stuck.

Comment: You may want to look at the examples in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector ; then you have to compute the generalized eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$, since it has an algebraic multiplicity of 2

Comment: Do you have to use the Jordan normal form to solve this? There’s a way to do it using Cayley-Hamilton that doesn’t require computing any eigenvectors at all.

Comment: You might also want to recompute those eigenvalues. The ones you have say that $A$ is a rank-one matrix, which it certainly isn’t. Also, $Av_{\lambda_3}\ne-2v_{\lambda_3}$, so you probably forgot to include the factor of $1/2$.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $-\lambda^3 - 2 \lambda^2 - \lambda=0$ which produces the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=-1$ and $\lambda_3=0$.

Comment: Since the eigenvalue $-1$ has algebraic multiplicity 2, I have to use the generalized eigenvector to complete the set of vectors, but it doesn't seem to work. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram alpha [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+normal+form+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22JordanDecompositionCalculator%22%2C+%22theMatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B-1%2F2%2C1%2F2%2C-1%2F2%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+-1%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B1%2F2%2C+-1%2F2%2C+-1%2F2%7D%7D%22)
\begin{eqnarray}
J&=& \begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix},\ \mbox{and}\\
S &=& \begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1\\
1&-1&1\\
1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\ .
\end{eqnarray}
Since
$$
J^n = \left(-1\right)^n\begin{bmatrix}
1&-n&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
$$
e^{tJ} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n J^n}{n!}=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-t)^n}{n!}&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\frac{(-t)^n}{n!}&0\\
0&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-t)^n}{n!}&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\\
=\ \begin{bmatrix}
e^{-t}&te^{-t}&0\\
0&e^{-t}&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{tA} &=& S\, e^{tJ} S^{-1}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
e^{-t}&-e^{-t}&e^{-t}\\
(t-1)\,e^{-t}&(1-t)\,e^{-t}&(1+t)\,e^{-t}\\
te^{-t}&-te^{-t}&(2+t)\,e^{-t}
\end{bmatrix}\ .
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I don't how to have $e^{tA}=e^{tSAS^{-1}}=e^S.e^{tA}.e^{S^{-1}}$?

Comment: Neither of those equations is true.  What *is* true is that $\ e^{tA}=e^{tSJS^{-1}}=Se^{tJ}S^{-1}\ $.